# expo SplashScreen showing white page after the splash screen if used with NavigationContainer

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I have the following code

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, I18nManager, DevSettings } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import * as Updates from "expo-updates";
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

import Login from "./screens/Login";
import RNRestart from "react-native-restart";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {


  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'GE SS Text Light Light': require('./assets/fonts/GE_SS_TEXT_LIGHT.otf'),
  });
  console.log("fontsLoaded",fontsLoaded);
  const [isSignedIn, setisSignedIn] = useState(true);

  const languageRestart = async () => {
    await I18nManager.forceRTL(true).then(() => {
      console.log("restarted");
      RNRestart.Restart();
    });
    //changing language based on what was chosen
   
  };

 

  useEffect(async () => {
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
    RNRestart.Restart();

    //await Updates.reloadAsync();
    if (!I18nManager.isRTL) {
      I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
      Updates.reloadAsync();
     

    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(fontsLoaded){
      setAppIsReady(true)
    }
      },[fontsLoaded]);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
     
      
    
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  
  return (
    <View  onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
    
    <StatusBar style={{ height: 100 }} />
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        {isSignedIn ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

When app started i can see the SplashScreen is showing without but if the state "appIsReady" is changed to true, only white page showing .

If i replace the code:-

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        {isSignedIn ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

With:-

```
<Login/>
```

Every thing works fine, it seems that issue only occurs if i use the react-navigation.

How can i use expo splash page with react navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding style={{ flex: 1 }} to the parent view

```
<View  onLayout={onLayoutRootView} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    
    <StatusBar style={{ height: 100 }} />
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        {isSignedIn ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  </View>
```